# Speech recognition on docker image

Tags: python, linux, docker, flask, dockerfile

I am able to build an image from the file. However, when I try to use the speech recognition I receive an error.
This is my dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.9
## user creation and application dir
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install apt-utils
RUN apt-get install -y libasound-dev libportaudio2 libportaudiocpp0 portaudio19-dev libsndfile1
RUN apt-get install -y alsa-utils
RUN mkdir /app
RUN useradd -m worker
RUN chown worker /app

#modifying python path and upgrading pip
USER worker
ENV PATH="/home/worker/.local/bin:${PATH}"
RUN python -m pip install --upgrade pip
WORKDIR /app

#adding main files
ADD speech.py /app
ADD requirements.txt /app

#installing requirements
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN pip install SpeechRecognition
RUN pip install pyaudio
ADD templates /app/templates


EXPOSE 5000
CMD ["python", "speech.py"]
```

speech.py script

```
import speech_recognition as sr
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, session

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'command'


@app.route('/spee')
def home():
    return render_template('speech.html')


@app.route('/speech', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def speech():
    try:
        li = []
        listen(li)
        session['command'] = li[0]
        ht =  '''<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"><head>
</head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    '''
        ht+= f'<h1> did you mean: "{li[0]}"'
        ht+='''
    <form action="/search">
      <button type="submit">Yes</button>
    </form>
    <form action="/">
      <button type="submit">No</button>
    </form>


</html>'''
        return ht
    except:
        return 'speech not recognized'


@app.route('/search', methods=['POST'])
def search():
    command = session['command']
    url = f'https://www.google.com/search?q={command}'
    return redirect(url)


def listen(li):
    import speech_recognition as sr

    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        audio = r.listen(source)
        command = r.recognize_google(audio)
    li.append(command)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', )
```

Here is the error, I tried installing alsa-utils. I tried to run the docker with privileged flag.
And I tried removing the user and performing all the commands as root. None of those worked

```
ALSA lib confmisc.c:767:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4745:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_driver returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:392:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
ALSA lib conf.c:4745:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1246:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name
ALSA lib conf.c:4745:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5233:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM sysdefault
ALSA lib confmisc.c:767:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4745:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_driver returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:392:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
ALSA lib conf.c:4745:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1246:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name
ALSA lib conf.c:4745:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5233:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM sysdefault
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.front
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround21
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround21
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround40
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround41
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround50
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround51
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround71
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.iec958
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.iec958
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.iec958
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.hdmi
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.hdmi
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.modem
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.modem
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.phoneline
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.phoneline
ALSA lib confmisc.c:767:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4745:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_driver returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:392:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
ALSA lib conf.c:4745:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1246:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name
ALSA lib conf.c:4745:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5233:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM default
ALSA lib confmisc.c:767:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4745:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_driver returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:392:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
ALSA lib conf.c:4745:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:4745:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5233:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM default
ALSA lib confmisc.c:767:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4745:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_driver returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:392:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
ALSA lib conf.c:4745:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1246:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name
ALSA lib conf.c:4745:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5233:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM dmix
```

Ran lspci shows nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hej! Try adding the following flags `-v /dev/snd:/dev/snd -e AUDIODEV="hw:Device, 0"` to your `docker run` command

Find your device name with `aplay -l`.
In my case it gave me:
`card 2: Device [USB PnP Audio Device], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]`
So I had to write -e AUDIODEV="hw:Device, 0"

Comment: I see , it is possible to detect the speaker microphone even if it is not the one who runs the docker?

Comment: Unforunatly it's not possible as far as I know (。﹏。*)

Comment: That is fine thanks!!